# Adding authorization header to ag-grid request

Tags: javascript, ag-grid

I am trying ag-grid for the first time.
In order to get data for the grid I need to call a url and pass a jwt token as a request header.

Usually I add this as an `"Authorization: Bearer token"` header.
Can this be done in ag-grid?

The simple tutorial has an example calling `aggrid.simpleHttpRequest({url:....})` to fetch data but this seems to only allow a url string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `simpleHttpRequest` method is a convenience method that AG Grid use in their documentation to make it easier to read.

It is much easier to use a fetch directly, then you have access to the full fetch api, including configuring the headers.

e.g. to set AG Grid data with a `fetch` then use the `setRowData` method on the api to add the data retrieved from the API call to the grid.

```
fetch('https://api.myjson.com/bins/15psn9').
then(function (response) {
        return response.json();
    }).then(function (data) {
        gridOptions.api.setRowData(data);
    })
```

The above code is a snippet from the AG Grid blog post "Get started with JavaScript Grid in 5 minutes" https://blog.ag-grid.com/get-started-with-javascript-grid-in-5-minutes/

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.